# setup civiCRM on windows 8

Tags: php, windows-8, open-source, civicrm

Please could anybody direct me on how to setup civiCRM on my windows OS and also code with it. I am totally new to this type of platform and with no clue on how to go about anything, however, I have a strong knowledge of PHP and php based frameworks like laravel and lumen. I believe if directed on what to do I should be able to standard on my own. I have tried google but nothing significant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to install Drupal on your local windows machine with Xampp, it's quite straight forward:

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

When all set up follow these steps, if you encounter any errors, let me know, I've been through them already!

1. Fetch file from here:
   https://civicrm.org/download version 5.XXXX is fine
2. download file and extract it
3. Paste the extracted files in the modules folder, and make sure the module folder name is civicrm, small caps
4. Navigate to :

http://localhost/crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php

5. If it doesn’t let install because of permission issues: Comment out these lines around line 265 of index.php on this file:

C:\Core\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm3\sites\all\modules\civicrm\install

```
/* if ((!function_exists(‘user_access’)) || (!user_access(‘administer site 
configuration’))) {
$errorTitle = ts(“You don’t have permission to access this page”);
$errorMsg = ts(“The installer can only be run by a user with the permission to 
administer site configuration.”);
errorDisplayPage($errorTitle, $errorMsg);
exit();
}
 */
```

6. When installing , share database with Drupal, that way you can use bakcup migrate to backup civiCRM settings and data. And maybe load sample data checked.

Comment: Thank you vincent. How can I contact you directly. Thanks

Comment: There are some questions I would love to ask such as creating an extension and hooks, civicrm docs is not clear to me. Thanks @Bruno Vincent